# How to check version of installed wine and uninstall it?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I want to know the version of wine I have installed.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
I thought in general for uninstallation without knowing version I can use this command

```
sudo apt-get purge wine\*
```

but this command made my system unstable.
So now what can I do to remove wine from my system

Comment: Note that the `fooapp --version` answers apply to the majority of applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `sudo apt-get purge wine` and then `rm -rf ~/.wine`. The second command will remove your configuration in your home directory, do not run that second command if you intend to re-install wine.

With apt-get you have 2 options to remove a package.

remove removes the package, but leaves the configuration files in place. purge removes the package + configuration files.

See [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/apt-get.8.html) for details.

> purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
>              purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

apt-get, however, leaves user files in your home directory. Files in your home directory must be manually removed. They are "dot" or .files and thus hidden.

the `rm` command removes the files, the `-r`, flag is for recursive and `-f` is force (do not ask for confirmation). The `-r` and `-f` flags should be used with caution as they will delete files and directories without warning.

See [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/rm.1.html) for details.

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to explain both command in brief

Comment: I added some detail and some links

Answer (score 20):

Open a terminal, write the following line in terminal,

```
wine --version
```